# image cannot update on vue js with axios

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with the image update feature on vue js using axios.  I'm successfully creating data with image, but now I'm stack in update the image

this is the template code section

```
   <template>
  <q-page-container>
    <transition
      enter-active-class="animated fadeInLeft"
      leave-active-class="animated fadeOutRight"
      appear
      :duration="700"
    >
      <q-page>
        <q-toolbar elevated class="text-primary">
          <q-btn
            flat
            round
            dense
            icon="arrow_back"
            @click="$router.push('/produk')"
          />
          <q-toolbar-title>
            Edit produk
          </q-toolbar-title>
        </q-toolbar>
        <form>
          <div class="row justify-center">
            <p style=" width:90%; margin-top:10px;">Nama barang :</p>
            <q-input
              name="namaproduk"
              dense
              outlined
              v-model="dataproduk.namaproduk"
              lazy-rules
              :rules="[
                val => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please type something'
              ]"
              label="Nama produk"
              style="width:90%; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom: 20px; justify-content: center;"
            />
            <p style=" width:90%; ">Harga barang :</p>
            <q-input
              name="harga"
              dense
              outlined
              v-model="dataproduk.harga"
              type="number"
              label="Harga produk"
              style="width:90%; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom: 20px; justify-content: center;"
              lazy-rules
              :rules="[
                val => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please type something'
              ]"
            />
            <p style=" width:90%;">Deskripsi :</p>
            <q-editor
              v-if="dataproduk.deskripsi"
              name="deskripsi"
              style="width:90%; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom: 20px; justify-content: center;"
              v-model="dataproduk.deskripsi"
              :definitions="{
                bold: { label: 'Bold', icon: null, tip: 'My bold tooltip' }
              }"
            />
            <p style=" width:90%;">Gambar sekarang :</p>
            <img
              v-if="dataproduk.gambar"
              :src="'http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/' + dataproduk.gambar"
              style="width:150px; height:150px;"
            />
            <p style=" width:90%;">Ubah Gambar :</p>
            <q-file
              name="gambar"
              @change="handleFileObject()"
              dense
              outlined
              v-model="image"
              label="Gambar produk"
              style="width:90%; margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom: 20px; "
            />
            <q-btn
              @click.prevent="ubah"
              type="submit"
              dense
              color="primary"
              label="Edit"
              style="width:90%; margin: 20px; justify-content: center;"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </q-page>
    </transition>
  </q-page-container>
</template>
```

This method is used to modify data

```
methods: {
handleFileObject() {
  this.image = this.$refs.file.files[0];
},
ubah() {
  var dataproduk = new FormData();
  dataproduk.append("namaproduk", this.dataproduk.namaproduk);
  dataproduk.append("harga", this.dataproduk.harga);
  dataproduk.append("deskripsi", this.dataproduk.deskripsi);
  dataproduk.append("gambar", this.image);
  _.each(this.dataproduk, (value, key) => {
    dataproduk.append(key, value);
  });
  axios
    .put(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/produk/update/" + this.id,
      this.dataproduk,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type":
            "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" +
            Math.random()
              .toString()
              .substr(2)
        }
      }
    )
    .then(response => this.$router.push("/indexadmin"))
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.response.status === 422) {
        this.errors = [];
        _.each(err.response.data.errors, error => {
          _.each(error, e => {
            this.errors.push(e);
          });
        });
      }
    });
}
```

if I do not use "content-type:multipart/form-data" data in the form of strings and integers it is successfully changed. if I use "content-type:multipart/form-data" then all data fails to be update

Here's an error adding "content-type:multipart/form-data"

> exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
> file: "D:\magang\serverapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php"
> line: 678
> message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'namaproduk' cannot be null (SQL: update `produkdatas` set `namaproduk` = ?, `deskripsi` = ?, `harga` = ?, `produkdatas`.`updated_at` = 2021-04-09 01:50:07 where `id` = 13)"
> trace: [{file: "D:\magang\serverapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php",…},…]

Comment: This issue is server-side in nature. Reading the excepting `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'namaproduk' cannot be null ` You have a constraint in your DBMS preventing the column `namaproduk` from being null. Meaning that there is no data being added to that column. Add some data to that column and it will insert or change the column constraints to allow null by removing `not null` in the table definition. If that is your blob column, make sure that you are handling blobs correctly on the server-side

Comment: I have tried, but the data that I will change to value becomes null after submitting it

Comment: This is a server-side issue, not an Axios or Vue one.  This issue stems from trying to insert a blob incorrectly into whatever database you are using. Here is an example for PHP and Mysql https://phppot.com/php/mysql-blob-using-php/

Comment: but when adding data was successful

Answer (score 1):

Hello there are  working example of file input for laravel + vue

```
<img v-if="user.photo" class="block w-8 h-8 rounded-full ml-4" :src="user.photo" />

 <file-input v-model="form.photo" :error="form.errors.photo" class="pr-6 pb-8 w-full lg:w-1/2" type="file" accept="image/*" label="Photo" />
```

FileInput.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label v-if="label" class="form-label">{{ label }}:</label>
    <div class="form-input p-0" :class="{ error: errors.length }">
      <input ref="file" type="file" :accept="accept" class="hidden" @change="change" />
      <div v-if="!value" class="p-2">
        <button type="button" class="px-4 py-1 bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-sm text-xs font-medium text-white" @click="browse">
          Browse
        </button>
      </div>
      <div v-else class="flex items-center justify-between p-2">
        <div class="flex-1 pr-1">
          {{ value.name }} <span class="text-gray-500 text-xs">({{ filesize(value.size) }})</span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="px-4 py-1 bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-700 rounded-sm text-xs font-medium text-white" @click="remove">
          Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="errors.length" class="form-error">{{ errors[0] }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: File,
    label: String,
    accept: String,
    errors: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  watch: {
    value(value) {
      if (!value) {
        this.$refs.file.value = ''
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    filesize(size) {
      var i = Math.floor(Math.log(size) / Math.log(1024))
      return (size / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(2) * 1 + ' ' + ['B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'][i]
    },
    browse() {
      this.$refs.file.click()
    },
    change(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.files[0])
    },
    remove() {
      this.$emit('input', null)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```